# Windows 10 Answer File (unattend.xml)

Tags: xml, windows, windows-10

I'm trying to create a Windows 10 image with sysprep but I have a problem.
I can't find a setting in the unattend file where I disable to send data to Microsoft or turn off my location.

Here are screenshots how one can do it manually.
[image: Step 1]
[image: Step 2]

Here is my unattend File:

```
<settings pass="windowsPE">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <SetupUILanguage>
            <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
        </SetupUILanguage>
        <InputLocale>de-CH</InputLocale>
        <SystemLocale>de-CH</SystemLocale>
        <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
        <UserLocale>de-CH</UserLocale>
    </component>
</settings>

<settings pass="oobeSystem">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="AMD64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <OOBE>
            <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
            <HideLocalAccountScreen>true</HideLocalAccountScreen>
            <HideOEMRegistrationScreen>true</HideOEMRegistrationScreen>
            <HideOnlineAccountScreens>true</HideOnlineAccountScreens>
            <ProductKey>XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX</ProductKey>
            <NetworkLocation>Work</NetworkLocation>
            <ProtectYourPC>3</ProtectYourPC>
            <SkipMachineOOBE>true</SkipMachineOOBE>
            <SkipUserOOBE>true</SkipUserOOBE>
        </OOBE>
    </component>
</settings>
<cpi:offlineImage cpi:source="" xmlns:cpi="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:cpi" />
```

Answer (score 0):

All possible settings/components are described well [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699038.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
This might help in your case regarding (not)sending data:

> The Microsoft-Windows-SQMAPI component implements the Windows Customer Experience Improvement Program (CEIP). If the component is enabled, it collects and sends data to Microsoft about the use of Windows. Participation in this program is voluntary, and the results are recorded to implement improvements in future releases.
>
> This setting has no effect on Server Core installations.

`<CEIPEnabled>false</CEIPEnabled>` [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-sqmapi)

> DisableWER disables Windows® Error Reporting. You may want to disable error-reporting functionality when you are deploying Windows in large, managed environments.

`<DisableWER>1</DisableWER>`[source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff715727.aspx)
*0 Enables Windows Error Reporting*
*1 Disables Windows Error Reporting*

Answer (score 0):

```
<NetworkLocation>Work</NetworkLocation>
```

That one is invalid for at least 1709+, probably all win 10.

Instead you need to

```
<CommandLine>powershell -Noninteractive -Command &quot;&amp; {(Get-NetConnectionProfile).Name | Set-NetConnectionProfile
-NetCategory Private}&quot;  *&gt; c:\windows\temp\4.log</CommandLine>
```

in FirstLogonCommands